# How to enable mouse control (accessibility?) for Java WebStart application?

Tags: mojave, mouse, java, accessibility

We have an demo application that our salesman launches through Java WebStart.  It works fine, exception on Macs (running MoJave) for a section that uses AssertJ Swing to drive the mouse and the keyboard.

I read here (https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-swing/issues/224) that Mac OS X won't let an application drive the mouse unless it is marked as an Accessibility application.  Unfortunately, the solution there is for Eclipse, which we aren't using.  We do not see Java, Java WebStart or our application in the list for things that can be marked as an Accessibility application.

So, how do we mark Java WebStart (or our Java WebStart application) as an Accessibility application?  Or is there another way to give our application control of the mouse?

**Update 1**

Java WebStart and AssertJ Swing work correctly under Sierra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We set the Web Browser that was launching the Java WebStart application to be an Accessiblity Application and then it worked correctly!